# Ошибки на сайте WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, домен

Переносил сайт на WP с одного домена на другой. 
После переноса появилось такое сообщение

```html
Warning: fopen(/home/luxevide/ТутСайт/www/wp-content/plugins/photography-portfolio/photography-portfolio.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/luxevide/ТутСайт/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4883

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/luxevide/ТутСайт/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4886

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/luxevide/ТутСайт/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4889
```

Вот код этих строк 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема ?

Благодарю за ответы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Answer (score 0):

Основная проблема - в `fopen` передается неправильный путь, либо файл не существует.

Если `fopen` завершается с ошибкой, то он возвращает `FALSE`, а не дескриптор. Поэтому в `$fp` лежит `FALSE`. В функции  `fread` и `fclose` передается `$fp` и они вызывают ошибку, т.к. не работают с типом `BOOL`.

Нужно задать корректный путь к файлу в `$file` и всё будет работать правильно.

Comment: То есть, это значит, что во время переноса сайта на другой домен, где-то в файлах остался прописан старый адрес и его нужно заменить на новый ?

Comment: @Quantum да, так же Wordpress хранит абсолютные ссылки в БД, нужно там тоже поискать.

Comment: а есть какой-нибудь плагин или что-то вроде, который просканирует файлы в директории и в БД, на предмет соответствий с указанным доменом ?

Comment: @Quantum не могу утверждать, что таких нету, но я о таких не слышал. Вам KAGGDesign скинул ссылку на вопрос, в ответе на который рассмотрены плагины для "правильного" переноса, я рекомендую заново перенести воспользовавшись одним из плагинов. 

[Ссылка на вопрос со списком плагинов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)